# What are the workarounds when Composer dependencies conflict in versions?

Tags: composer-php

My projects depends on two packages, `A` and `B`, and they both depend on `some-library`, unfortunately in incompatible versions:

- `A` depends on `lib` @ 1.0
- `B` depends on `lib` @ 2.0

This is unresolvable by Composer because PHP can only load a single version of a class / interface at runtime.

What are my options? **I am fine with "ugly" workarounds as long as they are automated.** Doing fragile and manual work like forking `A` and upgrading its usage of `some-library` is something I'd like to avoid at all costs.

Comment: [Version aliasing](https://garthkerr.com/alias-a-version-for-composer/)

Comment: You may try to use https://github.com/humbug/php-scoper to prepare build of one package with prefixed dependencies.

Comment: Could you name your dependencies A & B and which common lib they depend upon? Maybe if they are FOSS & still active you or someone else could open a Pull Request. You could also fork A and update lib to 2.x in yourself, if you are comfortable with the additional overhead of maintaining it. Composer allows you to override the repository to fetch the library from your repository instead of an official version.

Answer (score 0):

There are no workarounds. By design, **Composer** assumes that your project uses consistent dependencies and everything is maintained valid.

As mentioned in the comments, you can **prefix the dependencies** to isolate the part of the project that needs a particular library version. In this way, the prefixed code is consistent in Composer terms and you can continue developing with the latest versions.

These are a couple of prefixers that I can recommend:

[humbug/php-scoper](https://github.com/humbug/php-scoper) is a well-known tool that can prefix code based on Search & Replace steps (Finders and Patchers).

[PHP-Prefixer](https://php-prefixer.com) is an automated online service to apply prefixes to Composer dependencies, based on `composer.json` definitions. You define the new namespace and prefix for your project.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead PHP-Prefixer developer.